# Twist on St. Petersberg Paradox

Tags: probability, statistics, expectation

> Consider the St. Petersburg paradox, except that you
>   receive $n$ rather than 2<sup>n</sup>
>   if the game lasts for *n* rounds. What is the fair value of this
>   game? What if the payoff is $n$<sup>2</sup>?

So, after doing the St. Petersburg paradox, I calculated the E(2<sup>n</sup>) = 4. If we simply make it *n*, would it not just be 2? And $n$<sup>2</sup> is 16? Or is that mistaken?

Thanks!

Comment: This question would be greatly improved if you defined the St Petersburg paradox so people don't have to google it to answer the question.

Comment: I know what the st petersburg paradox is and I still find it hard to follow what you say after the question. What do you mean by $E(2^n) = 4$? In the St Petersburg paradox, if $N$ is the number of rounds you last and $2^N$ is your payoff, then $E(2^N) = \infty.$ (Thus the paradox.) Agree w/ Stella, you should precisely define the game and payoff in the question.

Comment: Well, given that N~FS(1/2), that makes the E(N) = 2.

Comment: @CobyR. Do mind clarifying what the notation $FS(1/2)$ refers to?

Comment: You gotta @ people if you want them to hear. The notation $FS(1/2)$ is unfamiliar to me as well but from context and your followup I'm guessing it's what most call the Geometric distribution with $p=1/2.$ If I've interpreted you correctly, although you are correct that $E(N)=2,$ it is *not* true that $E(2^N= (2^{E(N)}.$ Expectations do not work that way. In this case, actually $E(2^N) = \infty.$ (My interpretation of what you're saying may be wrong since this stlll doesn't explain where $E(n^2)=16$ came from.)